# send clean url with MapRoute mvc5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, maproute

I'm new in mvc5, and I don't understand well how to form a **clean url**.

Right now my RouteConfig.cs file looks like :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Categorie",
            url: "{urlFormer}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ListOrGrid", action = "ListOrGrid", id = UrlParameter.Optional, urlFormer = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And I call this with :

```
@Url.Action("ListOrGrid", "ListOrGrid", new { id = cat.Categorie_Id, urlFormer = GlobalFunction.nomCategories(cat.Categorie_Id) })
```

The function `GlobalFunction.nomCategories(short id)` transform the id of categories in my table into a String

and my urls have this form : `https://localhost:44375/ListOrGrid/ListOrGrid/12?urlFormer=Mode%2FFemmes%2FVetements%2FJupes`

But I wanting the url looks like : `https://localhost:44375/Mode/Femmes/Vetements/Jupes`

How can i send my categorie id through the route "Categorie" to a controller without print it in the url like the "default" MapRoute ?

Comment: What is the actual value of `urlFormer`? And you need a specific route for `Categorie` and it needs to be before the `Default` route. But you will never be able to get the url you desire because it needs to include at least something to identify the controller/action

Comment: The actual value of urlformer is written in my post : `Mode%2FFemmes%2FVetements%2FJupes` from this function `GlobalFunction.nomCategories(cat.Categorie_Id)`.

why i needed to place it before the `default` route ?

why i can't have a clean url ? is there no way to achieve that ?

Comment: Because routes are match in order. And `https://localhost:44375/Mode/Femmes/Vetements/Jupes` means you call ing the `Femmes` method of `ModeController` and passing values for parameters named `Vetements` and `Jupes`. I suggest you do some research on routing in MVC.

Comment: The routing rule of thumb is to place most specific routes in top by order, and most generic route in bottom. Note that it is impossible to hide `id` part there since you need to pass `id` parameter, also the `urlFormer` should be split into 3 other optional parameters to build clean former URL.